# Is It Okay To Use the Content of Scholars Or Hadith To Earn Money on Youtube?

Tags: halal-haram, money, work, internet

Is it okay to earn money by uploading the content of scholars like Molana Tariq Jameel Bayan or Noman Khan etc on Youtube Or Can I record a Hadith in my Voice by reading it from a book and earn from it through Youtube? And I believe that the Content of Scholars is not Copyright like on different Apps it's Available?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts especially if somebody spent efforts to answer it!

Comment: Please don't ask questions related to Fiqh on this site as this is not a Fatwa site, anyone can answer here. Mostly, questions related to Qur'an and Hadith are welcome. For Fatwas from credible scholars take a look at https://islamqa.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more like a juridicial issue. To keep it safe, I'd say send an e-mail to one of them in which you ask their permission to use their content.

But there are 4 main things to take into consideration when taking their content which is written in the Copyright Law of the USA and I think Youtube follows it too:

(1) the purpose and character of the use, including whether such use is of a
commercial nature or is for nonprofit educational purposes;

(2) the nature of the copyrighted work;

(3) the amount and substantiality of the portion used in relation to the copyrighted
work as a whole; and

(4) the effect of the use upon the potential market for or value of the copyrighted
work

Source:

https://www.copyright.gov/title17/title17.pdf

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: So you just cite a hadith. Why wouldn't it be allowed? You educate your audience. That's permissible and even encouraged both in Islam and western countried and Youtube's policy is fine with it.

Comment: Well on the first question I'd say yes of course you can make money with it.

Comment: Well I'd suggest as I said in my answer. You should send them an e-mail first in which you ask their permission to do so to avoid unnecessary conflicts.

Comment: But just look for answers yourself in hadith in works from Al Buchaari and Muslim for example.

Comment: Most people you mentioned took their knowledge from them.